# rate(elasticsearch_indices_get_missing_total) > 100

Tags: elasticsearch, prometheus

Is there any relationship between elasticsearch_indices_get_missing_total and elasticsearch_indices_merges_docs_total ?

I got rate(elasticsearch_indices_get_missing_total) > 100 alert, but I could not find exception log.

How can I monitor the service ip to check the situation of indices get missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a `missing` **index** and not an error but a missing **document**. So your application requested a document which is not in Elasticsearch. Maybe it got deleted, maybe never got indexed in the fist place, maybe user entered incorrect ID and system works as expected.

Also, `merges` is different thing entirely. Elasticsearch stores data in storage blobs called "segments" and it merges them together every once in a while because it's much more efficient to work with larger segments than with many small ones. So the doc count in merged segments is a very "internal" metric, only needed for very specific situations.